# Why, I am getting always false regex pattern match, How to test and debug it and at which point condition is become false?

Tags: java, regex

I have below String I am trying to write regex pattern in java

```
**String value = "ABC6072103325000100120190429R070001";**

 please consider space bar for the part of the string 
 ABC6 0721 033250001001 20190429 R 07 0001
```

- 1st part - CNV6

  Max length -> length always 4, Alphanumeric A-Z0-9
- 2nd Part - 0721

  length always 4, Only 0-9 Digits allowed
- 3rd part - 033250001001

  length always 12, only digits allowed
- 4th Part -   20190507,

  format always YYYYMMDD, only digits allowed max length 8
- 5th Part - R

  It is constant always R coming on this occurrence
- 6th part - 07

  only 2 digits allowed
- 7th part - 0001

  allowed 1-4 only digits

According to my knowledge, I have written below regex but in my every attempt it becomes false.

```
String s = "[A-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{16}[1-9][0-9]{3}[0(1-9)|1(0-2)][0(1-9)|1(0- 
9)|z(0-9)|3(0-1)](R0)(1-9)0(0-9){1,3}";
```

Below is My program

```
package regextest;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {
public static String regex ="[A-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{16}[1-9][0-9]{3}[0(1-9)|1(0-2)] \r\n[0(1-9)|1(0-9)|2(0-9)|3(0-1)](R0)(1-9)0(0-9){1,3}";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String stringToMatch = "ABC6072103325000100120190429R070001";
    boolean isValid = isValidRegex(stringToMatch);
    System.out.println("isValid : " + isValid);
}

public static boolean isValidRegex(String stringToMatch) {
    boolean isValid =false;

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(regex);

      // Now create a matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(stringToMatch);
      if (m.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Matched");
     isValid = true;
      }else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
         isValid = false;
      }
    return isValid;
}
}
```

> output - NO MATCH

Comment: @mayankbatra: Please help

Comment: `[..]` is character class which can match only *single* character from specified set like `[abc-e]` can match only one character which is either `a` or `b` or in range `c-e` which is `c`, `d` or `e`. So `[0(1-9)|1(0-2)]` `[0(1-9)|1(0- 
9)|z(0-9)|3(0-1)]`  doesn't look right here since first part boils down to `[0-9()|]` and second `[0-9()|z]`.

Comment: The requirements differ from your pattern in at the very least, the 3rd requirement (says 12, you have 16). Also not sure about whether you want optional whitespace or not between parts, but your pattern doesn't allow it.

Comment: Then your character classes are not going to parse what you expect. Anything between square brackets is considered a literal, and in alternative to all other enclosed characters (special cases aside).

Comment: I would use String pattern = "[A-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}[0-9]{12}[0-9]{8}R[0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}"; Yes you have a date in there, but dates are bad to check with regex.

Comment: @Mena :White space not allowed

Comment: @RalfRenz No I don't want to use date pattern in regex. for better understanding my problem that's why i have mentioned here

Comment: You are trying to create capturing groups`()` inside a character class `[]` which does not work, the character class matches the chars that are listed in it. This would match it `[A-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}\d{12}\d{8}R\d{2}\d{4}` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mk356O/1) Not sure what you want to group..

Comment: @GoluSharma You are welcome. I have added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56075926/5424988) with some explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your pattern:

In these parts `[0(1-9)|1(0-2)]` and `[0(1-9)|1(0-9)|z(0-9)|3(0-1)](` I think you are aiming to use the `|` as an OR, but that does not work in a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

The first part is for example equal to `[)(0-9]` due to 0 and the ranges 1-9 and 0-2. Therefore the second part will also not be suited to match a date like format.

To match the number of digits without the more specific date like pattern,you could use:

```
[A-Z\d]{4}\d{4}\d{12}\d{8}R\d{2}\d{4}
```

In Java

```
String regex = "[A-Z\\d]{4}\\d{4}\\d{12}\\d{8}R\\d{2}\\d{4}";
```

You could also use `[0-9]` instead of `\\d`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/suvy7C/1)

**Note**

To match a 'date like' pattern YYYYMMDD to narrow down the possible accepted digits, you might use the following regex but that will not validate a date itself.

```
^\d{4}(?:1[012]|0[1-9])(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BqQy4X/1)

Comment: How to become an expert in Regex can you please share some link and what is the best way to learn regex and become expertise

Comment: @VedPrakash You could check for example these websites which are a great resource https://www.rexegg.com/ and https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html. There are also great books about regex. See [this page](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-books.html) for books and resources. Another helpful way is to read explanations given by answers on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

How to test and debug a regex? Personnally I always use one of those websites who exist for this purpose. By example:

- https://regexr.com/
- https://regex101.com/
- https://www.regextester.com/

Most of them can show you what's wrong on your regex or even explain what they understand about it.

For your actual situation this regex should work fine

```
[A-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{16}[1-9][0-9]{3}[0(1-9)|1(0-2)][1-9][0-9]{2}R[0-9]{2}[0-9]{1,4}
```

Your regex started to not work at the end part of the date.

```
[0(1-9)|1(0-9)|z(0-9)|3(0-1)]
```

This part never match with the month and day part of the date so your regex never found an occurrence.

Comment: So what is the exact regex ? i am using this one now [A-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}\d{12}\d{8}R\d{2}\d{4} given by @The fourth bird

Comment: There is not one good answer in regex. It is possible that several work for the same situation. Actually, the version of @The fourth bird is more short and don't test the date. If you don't have to test date use this one.

Comment: @The fourth bird : Thanks you saved my life